# Dialog view did not find a record for the dialog

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

In my WIX SETUP i am getting the above mentioned error while uninstalling the setup.
This error occur only first time if i Repair or Remove my setup.

Any help is appreciable

logs error

```
> MSI (c) (A0:84) [04:09:50:433]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2803 
DEBUG: Error 2803:  Dialog View did not find a record for the dialog 
MSI (c) (A0:84) [04:09:50:433]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (A0:84) [04:09:50:433]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2867 
DEBUG: Error 2867:  The error dialog property is not set
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2867.
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be more information if you get a verbose log of the error, or post the entire 2803 error message (that's what it probably is) where it tells you the failing dialog. It usually means that your UI sequence is referring to a missing dialog.

Comment: I am getting below error

DEBUG: Error 2803:  Dialog View did not find a record for the dialog

Comment: If you examine the log a bit more carefully than just to tell us the error we already know about you may find something before the error that says what dialog it's trying to show. Unfortunately you haven't posted anything from before the error that shows what was going on. The error you are getting is perhaps being made worse by the fact that it's trying to tell you what's going on by showing an Error dialog, and there isn't one of those either. Your MSI file appears to be in a sorry state with multiple missing dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

The log won't help much.
The problem may be because you have wrong orders in your Publish sequence, for instance in invalid Order sequence like the following :

```
<Publish Dialog ...Order="1"></Publish>
<Publish Dialog ...Order="1"></Publish>
```